# Calculate future event due date with dayjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I want to use the dayjs JavaScript library or pure JavaScript to calculate next dues date (two weeks) from now and print it out on the screen. What I mean is that, an event is happening today and the next date it will happen is two weeks from today. Whenever the event happens, I will say the next event date is the two weeks' date. I am stuck after the little effort I have made so far with the code below. I will appreciate some help.

```
let today_event = dayjs();
today_event.format();

function eventDate()
{
console.log(`${today_event}`) //prints out today's date as I test it with this

}

eventDate(); //To call the function
```

That is what I have done so far trying to create a function for it. Now, I am stuck on how to go further and calculate a future date from the current date. Maybe, I am not even going about it the right way. So, I will appreciate every help.

Comment: Probably a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date.  Instead of calculating and adding a big number of ms, use the getDate() function in JS date. Now is `let d = new Date();` 14 days from now is `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 14)`

Comment: You need this: https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/add Now you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/7uhayf4e/

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `60 * 60 * 24 * 14 * 1000` to today's timestamp:

```js
const today = new Date();
const future = new Date(today.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 14) * 1000);

console.log("today:", today)
console.log("2 weeks from now:", future);
```